# If I make some new structure like Q, then can I use 'rewrite' tactic for my new structure in Coq?

Tags: coq

From $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of all rational numbers, I make some new structure $I$, and also make strict order and (equivalence) equality on $I$.

I want to use rewrite tactic for my defined relations (strict order, or equality).
For example,

```
H : a < const_I 0
H0 : const_I 0 == b
```

I want to write

```
rewrite H0 in H.
```

However, this writing tells me that "not a rewritable relation".

Is there a way to use some new defined relations with 'rewrite' tactic?

Comment: A MWE would help.  Are you trying to rewrite with an equivalence relation instead of a true equality?

Comment: If so how do you know that the inequality is still true after the rewrite? You would need a lemma showing your order respects the equivalence relation.  I think Coq has generalized rewriting for this purpose.

Comment: Coq surely needs to prevent you from naming the `<` relation as `==` and rewriting. So you should first prove theorems about your `==` to convince Coq it is rewritable.

Comment: Yes, there is! It's called [generalized rewriting](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html). As the others are saying, you need to prove some extra lemmas, and then `rewrite` will do the job.